# Cypress Test Fails: Getting "This DOM element likely became detached somewhere between the previous and current command"

Tags: reactjs, integration-testing, cypress

Issue - I am trying to fill all input fields in a given page with a given value and tests are failing currently with the below error :

cy.clear for an input element failed

"Cypress requires elements to be attached in DOM to interact with them"

The previous command that ran was cy.wrap
"This DOM element likely became detached somewhere between the previous and current command"

The custom command that is being used is given below which is causing the error but in local am not able to reproduce the issue but coming in our terminal

```
Cypress.command.add("inputs", (selector, value) => {
   cy.get(selector).each((element) => {
       cy.wrap(element).clear().type(value)
   })
})

added cy.inputs(selector) in the test.
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve similar issue faced is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Normally when Cypress throws a "detached element" error, you can re-query to get the fresh version of the element.

In this case, I found a `.focus()` was also needed.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("inputs", (selector, value) => {

  cy.get(selector).each((_, index) => {        // using the index not the element

    cy.get(`${selector}:nth(${index})`)        // query refresh
      .focus()
    
    cy.get(`${selector}:nth(${index})`)
      .should($el => {
        expect(Cypress.dom.isAttached($el), 'is attached').to.eq(true) // retry if false
      })
      .clear().type(value)
  })
})
```

The `.should($el => expect(Cypress.dom.isAttached($el)).to.eq(true))` is not strictly needed, at least in my scenario, but it can't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.should('have.text', '')` if the value is stored as innerText or `.should('have.value', '')` if the value is stored as a value. This will make sure that the assertions are automatically retried until they pass or time out.

```
Cypress.command.add("inputs", (selector, value) => {
   cy.get(selector).each((element) => {
       cy.wrap(element).clear().should('have.text', '').type(value)
   })
})
```

Also in your tests, I could see you are passing just one parameter selector, but your custom command is expecting selector and value both.

```
cy.inputs(selector,value)
```